# Where do I put the hot wire on a double pole 20 amp breaker?

Tags: electrical

Where do I put the hot wire on a double pole 20 amp breaker I have a 12/2 wire I have a black and white wire I need to know does the black go on top or bottom because there is 2 screws on the braker thanks

Comment: Do you mean a tandem breaker where there are two breakers that fit into a single slot? In this case they are both on the same leg and it doesn't matter.  If you are talking about an actual double-pole 240V breaker or a multi-wire branch circuit then you need 12/3 cable.

Comment: If you don't understand that both wires are hot, step away from the panel.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish?

A double pole breaker is used to supply either a 120/240V circuit, a straight 240V circuit, or a 120V multi-wire branch circuit.

If you're wiring a 240V circuit, the black wire goes to one terminal and the white goes to the other. If you're trying to wire a 120/240V circuit, or a multi-wire branch circuit,  you'll need another wire. If you're trying to wire a 120V circuit, you need a single pole breaker not a double pole.

Both terminals on a double pole breaker are hot.

Comment: And in the case of a straight 240V, the white should get marked with black tape to indicate it's hot.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter unless you want to follow a color convention that typically isn't used in residential work; primarily because most of the wire is cable assemblies and not 12/3 where you'd have a red wire as well.

The color convention I speak of is Black-Red (Black-Red-Blue for 3-phase). This means as you go down from the top and both sides of breakers in the [panel](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-100-Amp-20-Space-40-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Plug-On-Neutral-Breaker-Load-Center-with-Cover-Value-Pack-HOM2040M100PCVP/204836397?N=5yc1vZbm30) alternate in color.

1 Black 2 
3  Red  4 
5 Black 6 
. . .

A 2-pole breaker spans two colors. Depending on where it's at, the "proper" way could be top or bottom. But like I said, it doesn't matter in terms of delivering power or for code.

Comment: In this case it matters because they need a neutral, they have a ground they are not the same thing.

Comment: @EdBeal, I'm not reading it that way; where do they say they "need a neutral"?. They do have a white (12/2), but that doesn't imply a *need* for a grounded conductor.